# Unable to create WCF channel in portable class library

Tags: c#, wcf, portable-class-library

I'm hoping I've just missed something obvious and someone will point it out to me here.

I've created a PCL that contains my WCF service as well as the DTOs that it uses. The idea is to reference this on the server and implement the service, and also reference it on the client and use something like `ChannelFactory<T>` to create the channels and make the WCF calls.

I can do this without a problem in a standard class library, but the PCL has a limited subset of the classes available, and most of the classes I've tried to use are abstract.

Can someone please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ChannelFactory<T>` is not available in the PCL when you're targeting Windows 8 (WinRT) or Silverlight for that matter. Everything is assumed to be done with `ClientBase<T>`. This does suck as it creates a lot of ceremony around things, but if you use the "Service Reference" feature in Visual Studio (svcutil.exe on command line) it will generate the necessary plumbing for you.

Note that if you were able to drop Silverlight and also go with Windows **8.1** compatibility you will get `ChannelFactory<T>` back.

Comment: I'm targeting .NET 4.5, Silverlight 4 and higher, Windows Phone 7 and higher and .NET Store apps. The `System.ServiceModel` namespace is available to me, but only a subset of the classes are available. It's a different `System.ServiceModel.dll` than the assembly that's available in the 4.5 framework.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're looking for ChannelFactory*<T>* and that's not there in PCL when targeting WinRT, lemme update my answer.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using services references. I'm planning to give this assembly to other developers who want to write applications against my service. Are you suggesting I just create that reference to figure out how that works? I did, and while I don't want to say it isn't possible, I feel like I'm just reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @BrianBall You *can* hand roll your own, but you're not going to gain anything out of it as you're still exposing WCF specific details in your API. You *could* make the WCF service reference an internal implementation detail and just expose a "pure" .NET interface and class that completely hides the WCF details so that a) there are no WCFisms exposed at all by your surface API, b) consumers of your library can easily mock/fake your impl and c) you can move away from WCF down the line if say you rewrote everything as a "pure" REST service or something and none of your devs would be impacted.

Comment: I didn't realize changing the target frameworks in PCL actually changes the types that are available to you (though it makes sense). I dropped Silverlight and bumped up from Windows Phone 7 to Windows Phone 8 and now the `ClientFactory<T>` is available to me. I didn't see an option for windows 8.1 (I may be missing something). Thanks for your help!